# Rotating screen, my listview (ListActivity) disappears. android:configChanges flag makes no difference

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Rotating screen, my listview disappears. (API 19).
 I have a list adapter, db helper that I initialize in onCreate() in my ListActivity. Rotating screen, my listview disappears.
 Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2902944/398348, I tried

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.mypkg.MyListActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" >
```

It made no difference.

Also I am trying to understand - if my variables (list adapter etc) are recreated in onCreate(), then won't this be run anyway when activity is destroyed and recreated? Why do I need to do it again in onSaveInstanceState?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9550231/3286163

Comment: As to the second part of your question, I think that this will require that you post your code.

Comment: @singularhum the accepted answer in your link says that one should also implement this method - for a list activity, what would that mean for the layout resource file? `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
Then within the Activity override the onConfigurationChanged method and call setContentView to force the GUI layout to be re-done in the new orientation.

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
}`

Comment: @likejiujitsu you only need to override it if you want to manually adjust the layout (or do whatever you need) when the orientation changes. Refer to the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: @singularhum your answers are remarkably clear and informative. Please keep it up.

Comment: @MichaelAlanHuff Thanks but are you up-voting all my answers? This won't work anyway (will get reverted). If not sorry, someone is doing it. You can refer to [serial voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Comment: @singularhum that was me, I haven't had it get reverted before. Then again, I've not done that sort of thing in such quantity for a user before. I'll refrain from such things in the future.

Comment: @MichaelAlanHuff Yeah you did quite a bit in a short time-span so it will most likely get reverted in the next day or so as mentioned in the link in my last comment. At least you know now though. I appreciate the gesture nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of your question try changing the configChanges to

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

This is because when you switch orientation, the screen size changes as well.

Comment: that worked - is it necessary to implement onConfigurationChanged? see user singularhum's comment above

Comment: not in the most recent versions of android, but I think on older versions it might. What kind are you working with?

Comment: I am targeting API 19, and minimum API 11