# Android - crash during phone orientation in asynctask

Tags: java, android

When orientation of phone changes during loading of images from sdcard the application crashes due to

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

I am using the code from 
http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html

can any one Please help me

Comment: Is there any more info in the stack trace? Without that it's pretty hard to guess what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

When orientation of the phone changes, your activity is destroyed and created again. This can cause problems in many occasions. Do avoid this use:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

in the activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the reply. It worked fine. But i am using two layouts for two orientations. Portrait has 3 images and landscape has 5 images. But the image not adjusting properly as i arranged. Can you Please help me

Answer (score 0):

check: http://www.fattybeagle.com/2011/02/14/android-asynctasks-during-a-screen-rotation-part-i/

and: [How to handle an AsyncTask during Screen Rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620917/how-to-handle-an-asynctask-during-screen-rotation)