# How do I download Bitmaps and save to the SD card without running out of memory?

Tags: android, download, bitmap, android-3.0-honeycomb, bufferedinputstream

I'm looking for the best way to download an array of Bitmaps, modify them a bit and then save to the SD card.

I've heard that `ByteArrayOutputStream` is a bad idea to use because it loads the image into the RAM of the device. Instead I'm probably supposed to use something like a `BufferedInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`, however I don't know how I can alter the Bitmaps before saving them using this method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not like the answer: you cannot (at least, not with the Android framework).

The only option is to [downscale the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/3549021#3549021) so that it fits in memory; and regularly call `recycle()`and `System.gc()` to free memory as soon as possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I feared. I guess what I can do is download the images using a BufferedInputStream and then do my Bitmap manipulating afterwards. Not the best thing in the world, but luckily I was downloading the images using an AsyncTask, so I'll be able to do the Bitmap stuff in the onPostExecute() method. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: And then another recommendation: implement your long running tasks (downloading, image manipulation) with an `IntentService` rather than an `AsyncTask` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620917/how-to-handle-an-asynctask-during-screen-rotation http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your bitmap from your `InputStream` using:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

and then after you have processed your `Bitmap` and stored them you must use:

```
bm.recycle();
bm = null;
```

to avoid `OutOfMemoryExceptions` .

**EDIT:**

For writing it to a file:

```
OutputStream fos=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
int len;
while((len=is.read(buf))>0)
    fos.write(buf,0,len);
fos.close();
is.close();
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know that,  but how do I write the Bitmap to a file on the SD Card without using the ByteArrayOutputStream?

Comment: Thanks for that - but your code is reading directly from the inputStream and not the Bitmap :(