# How to start long running background task in android service

Tags: android, service, background

Having read most of the available documentation on Android services on the developer site and here in stackoverflow, I'm still confused by several aspects of running a service in a separate task. Hopefully someone can put me on the right track.

Let's say we have trival service framework such as

```
public class HliService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // We don't provide binding, so return null
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }
}
```

and in the manifest, I have

```
<service android:name=".HliService" android:process=":HLI_Comms"/>
```

so that the service runs in its own thread.

The intent of the service is to provide a background task that will communicate
to a device using a TCP socket and do some other stuff. At the risk of ignoring battery issues etc, basically I'd like it to run forever.

Something like

```
// Method that communicates using a TCP socket, and needs to send
// information back to the activity and receive messages from activity
// not shown here.
private void dummytask() {

    boolean keepGoing = true;
    while (keepGoing) {
        // do useful stuff in here
        // sets keepGoing false at some point
    }
    stopSelf();
}
```

What is the best way to initiate this method/task ?

I have looked at code in the developer site that uses a message handler and a looper, which I only partly understand, but it seems very complicated and perhaps more than I require?

I don't believe I can call this method from either `onCreate()` or `onStartCommand()` since then neither would complete when invoked from the system ? Should I start it with a timer or alarm?

I will need to add a message handler to communicate with the the gui activity, but since I'm starting the service in another thread (by virtue of the manifest "process" instruction), do I need to use AIDL instead?

I have also looked at using AysnchTask rather than extending Service, but it seems better suited to running a task and then terminating.

Comment: `while (keepGoing)` - if this is in another thread than the one that sets `keepGoing` to false `keepGoing` MUST BE `volatile` - read on the Java memory model

Comment: Please see this answer this may help you.
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13783477/2165080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so that the service run in its own thread.

That puts the service in its own *process*. This is generally something to be avoided, as it consumes extra RAM and CPU (for IPC). You can create a thread just by creating a `Thread` or any number of other means, most of which have been in Java for a decade or so.

> At the risk of ignoring battery issues etc, basically I'd like it to run forever.

It is pretty much impossible for a service to run forever. Users or the OS will get rid of your service eventually.

> What is the best way to initiate this method/task ?

Call `dummytask()` from a background thread.

> do I need to use AIDL instead?

No. Your service can broadcast an `Intent`, or invoke a `PendingIntent` supplied by the activity, or send a `Message` via a `Messenger` supplied by the activity, etc. The best would be to use the `LocalBroadcastManager` from the Android Support package, but that will not work across process boundaries, forcing you into more expensive communications options.

Comment: Ok - thanks @CommonsWare. I have looked at that method as well, but am also uncertain about certain aspects of implementing it - I'll do more research and perhaps post a follow-up question. I'll take your advice on not using the "process". BTW I do know that the service won't actually run forever - it was just a simplification. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a `IntentService` which you run by setting up a (regular) alarm (`AlarmManager.setRepeating`) with a `PendingIntent` in it. You can notify the UI by broadcasting an Intent from the `IntentService` and receiving it in your UI through a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Thanks @omoling -Isn't that more suited to just running a small task and then terminating, rather that initiating a long running process?