# How to Prevent other apps from stopping background service of my app?

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to  make an app which has got background service feature.But i need it to run continously till app is uninstalled.How can i achieve it using service.Can anyone help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Running service in background forever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783424/android-running-service-in-background-forever)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do these kind of assumptions on Android. Your app and related service might be killed for whatever. You can't guarantee that.

Answer (score -1):

Read the section on "Creating a started Service" here in [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Once a service is created, it will continue to run until it stops itself, or is stopped by the system. Why do you need it to run forever?

Comment: Actually i want to create service likes of viber.After installing viber it start its services ,but doesnot get killed by other apps if wanted.How can i achieve this.Can you help me out.