# Running app in background - but it is closed after a short period

Tags: android, background, system

I'm developing a Android gps-data-logger, which saves the gps position in a database. I've the following problem:

If there is too much traffic in background, if there are too much app open and the gps-data-logger don't find the gps position shortly, the app is closed by system and if the user opens the app again, the app restarts.

How can I avoid the closing of my app in background?

Comment: Perhaps use a service that runs continually in the background?

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: see my answer for some ideas & links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to try a service in the background, you can see this example: [Background Service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645298/how-to-start-long-running-background-task-in-android-service?rq=1). Or, there are many examples of services for free on the web, including google's own docs: [Android Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). Other sample code from a StackOverflow question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828639/android-get-gps-location-via-a-service).

Also, try this project that logs users gps: [gpslogger project source code](https://code.google.com/p/gpslogger/)