# Unable to use Fragment.setRetainInstance() as a replacement for Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

Tags: android, android-fragments

According to the Android API documentation, [Activity.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) has been deprecated in favor of [Fragment.setRetainInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29).

However, I have run into two separate situations where Fragment.setRetainInstance() doesn't seem to be feasible to use.

1. If the Fragment contains a WebView. According to [Diane Hackborne](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/cWnxkQ8RLeY/RA1n77EDeR8J), you cannot re-use a WebView across configuration changes. Which I guess means that you need to allow the Fragment to tear-down and re-create the WebView when the screen rotates, and use [WebView.saveState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState(android.os.Bundle)) and [WebView.restoreState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#restoreState(android.os.Bundle)) to restore the web view state.
2. If the Fragment belongs to a layout that no longer exists after the configuration change, when the FragmentManager tries to restore the Fragment, it will throw:

   ```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060091 for fragment
   ```

   This can occur (for example) if you have a two-fragment layout in landscape mode, but a one-fragment layout in portrait mode. When rotating from landscape to portrait, if setRetainInstance() set to true, neither Fragment gets destroyed, but one fragment no longer has a valid view to be re-attached to, hence the exception.

So, if you're building a Fragment-based application, and you need to retain data (for example references to running AsyncTasks) between configuration changes, and you can't use [Fragment.setRetainInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29), and there is no Fragment.onRetainNonConfigurationInstance(), what is the best approach to take?

Answer (score 8):

Even if you use `Fragment.setRetainInstance()`, the Fragment will still tear down its view and recreate it following a configuration change. That is, `onDestroyView()` and `onCreateView()` will be called in that sequence. Make sure to invalidate old references to the WebView in `onDestroyView()`. You do not have to worry about re-using a WebView - a new WebView will be recreated with the correct `Activity` context. This is somewhat irrelevant because for saving WebView state, you still need to call `WebView.saveState(Bundle)` in `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`, and `WebView.restoreState(Bundle)` in `Fragment.onViewCreated(Bundle)`. This just means that `Fragment.setRetainInstance()` is still compatible with use of WebViews.

The example you gave regarding a view container no longer existing in another orientation would mean that you do not need to retain any data - the fragment is not to be used at all after screen rotation.

In any case, instead of making a single Fragment handle both the UI and AsyncTask loading, you can separate them into two Fragments - the one with the AsyncTask does not need to be attached to the view hierarchy at all and can be set to be a retained instance. This simplifies your concerns and makes for a cleaner architecture. When the AsyncTask finishes, you need to call back to the UI fragment to deliver the results (e.g. findFragmentById/Tag, setTargetFragment, custom listeners...). The fragment managing the AsyncTask needs to be able to retrieve a reference to the new instance of the UI fragment after rotation.

Comment: About the view no longer existing problem, you are correct, but you are missing the case where the developer might want to have different layouts for different screens. For example, on some screens both portrait and landscape would have 2 panes, on some only the landscape would have 2 panes, and on some both of them would have 1 pane. Even if I call setRetainInstance(true) when there are only 2 panes, and call setRetainInstance(false) when there is one, i get the same exception. What can be done?

Comment: @mkuech that comment just says not to re-use the same WebView instance across configuration changes. We are not relying on that; onCreateView() is being called so we are making a new one each time.

Comment: @antonyt And apologies. It appears I crossed a few wires between this and some other SO questions. I'll be deleting my earlier comments to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there have been no answers to my question but here's what I ended up doing:

1. For *Fragments* containing a *WebView* which needs to be restored, override [Fragment.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and call [WebView.saveState(bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState%28android.os.Bundle%29). Then in [Fragment.onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29), call [webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#restoreState%28android.os.Bundle%29) if *savedInstanceState* is not null.
2. For *Fragments* containing live *AsyncTasks* that need to be preserved, override [Fragment.onDestroy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onDestroy%28%29) and save those tasks in my Application object. (Alternatively, stashing them in a [static variable](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/8550351/188197) is also suggested). Then in [Fragment.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29), check to see if those tasks are not null, and if so, restore them. (What that means is app dependent, but in my case I restore the callback to be invoked on the *Fragment* when the *AsyncTask* completes).

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it seems to address the problems I was having.

Still, I find this whole situation rather confusing (differentiating between *onSaveInstanceState()*, *onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()*, and *onDestroy()*, and deciding what you need to save under each scenario).