# Async task within fragments during screen oreintation

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-fragments, android-asynctask, screen-orientation

How to retain async task during screen oreintation. 
I have searched it much but not found any elegant solution to it.

What are my issues ::

1. I am having different layouts for portrait & landscape so cannot use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to restrict 
   activity recreation.
2. I cannot use `Fragment.setRetainInstance(boolean)` as I am having nested fragments so I am adding fragments to back stack 
   using `addToBackStack()`

   In this situation :

   `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` are not called.  This is metioned in the API docs.

   A bundle passed from `onSaveInstanceState()` is not received in `onCreateView()`. The passed-in Bundle is null. 
   So I will not get the saved instance of the `activity`

How to retain a async task in fragments to avoid crashing on orientation change.

**Or is there any other way for performing asynchronous task.**

Comment: Sorry if i don't understand, retain task means async task is not start again after orientation? OR u want to pass data to async taks after orientation?

Comment: @Neha i dont want to start again async task again on screen orientation.. Old one which is ongoing should we working instead of giving any memory leak as the old activity is destroyed.

Comment: So as per ur #1 point every time at orientation u destroy the current activity and start new (base on portrait/landscape mode). And bcaz of it ur async task lost bcaz activity which started is destroyed. So memory leak is issue Or u don't know from where async task need to start like data lost.?

Comment: This questiion could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417885/android-fragments-retaining-an-asynctask-during-screen-rotation-or-configuratio?rq=1

Comment: @Neha async task is lost becoz activity would be destroyed.

Comment: I believe your first asumption is false. Can't you handle `configChanges` and on configuration change loading the appropriate layout ?

Comment: @AntoineMarques yes that can be done. but for it i need to remove older view and loader new layout according to orientation which sometimes slow downs rendering.. and shows new layout after a lag..

Comment: As i not tested it but a suggestion u can implement OrientationEventListener and on orientation change cancel the async task and start it again on new activity onCreateView().

Comment: @Neha thnks buddy for suggestions but cancelling async task and restarting again could cause task to run long,by again n again restarting task. As screen orientation change can be frequent.

Comment: @Jewel sorry its not useful another suggestion is temporarily locking the screen in onPreExecute(), and unlocking it in onPostExecute(). Though this will change behave (make sense if your task progress bar/or loading screen).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a retain instance of a Fragment you should use a [Service or an IntentService](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to run your Task. The idea of a Service is that it keep processing independent what happens in an Activity. Because you didn't say someething about the Tasks work, decide which one fits best to your App.

To run an AsyncTask in an Activity is usually a bad idea, because of the fact that the Activity can be destroyed by the system or while orientation changes. Now there are plenty of work arounds out there to deal with this, like the retain Fragment approach. But these are having some disadvantages, like the `onSaveInstanceState()` point you noted. And all work arounds deal with the same thing: keeping the reference.

I don't know why it's not very popular to use a Service, which is the easiest way to run an async task (of any kind) without getting headaches while thinking about how to hold a reference to it.

Comment: thnks for response. Can we display any kind of progress notification while using service. I am not having idea of it. What about using `Loader` instead of `AsyncTask`. Any comment on using it.

Comment: You can use [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), which is the recommended way by the design guides.

Comment: but i will not able to freeze fragments using notifications. As my fragment data will be dependent of the data from web servies. If I use services for it than how would I manage it.

Comment: Try [this tutorial](https://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/) to see how to provide the data from a Service to the Activity.

Comment: Ohh yes using receivers we can update data. But i guess we cannot show any progress dialog while service is ongoing the background task.

Comment: Why not? If the Activity is visible you can update a ProgressBar with onProgressUpdate() in your AsyncTask using a callback.

Comment: you suggested toswitch on services rather than `AsyncTask`. My doubt was how to show progress in actvity while using servies for asynchronous task.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try launching your `AsyncTask` in its own task (see `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`) so its lifecycle becomes independent of your `Activity` being destroyed, then recreated.

You can then comunicate with using a `Handler` for retrieving results and/or progress.