# IllegalStateException fragment not attached to activity in onPostExecute after rotation but onDetach not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-dialogfragment

I've an AppCompatActivity that uses the NavigationDrawer pattern, managing some fragments. In one of these, that has no `setRetainInstance(true)`, I show a DialogFragment with a ProgressDialog inside and an AsyncTask with this code:

```
SavingLoader savingLoader = SavingLoader.newInstance(savingLoaderMaxValue);
savingLoader.show(getChildFragmentManager(), SAVING_LOADER_TAG);
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

Where the `SavingLoader` class is this one:

```
public class SavingLoader extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String MAX_VALUE_TAG = "MAX_VALUE_TAG";
    private static final String PROGRESS_VALUE_TAG = "PROGRESS_VALUE_TAG";

    public static SavingLoader newInstance(int max_value){
        SavingLoader s = new SavingLoader();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(MAX_VALUE_TAG, max_value);
        s.setArguments(args);
        return s;
    }

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public SavingLoader(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setCancelable(false);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), getTheme());
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.dialog_title_saving));
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_message_saving));
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        int max = (savedInstanceState == null ?
            getArguments().getInt(MAX_VALUE_TAG) : savedInstanceState.getInt(MAX_VALUE_TAG));
        if (max >= 1){
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            dialog.setProgress((savedInstanceState == null ?
                0 : savedInstanceState.getInt(PROGRESS_VALUE_TAG)));
            dialog.setMax(max);
        } else dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(MAX_VALUE_TAG, dialog.getMax());
        outState.putInt(PROGRESS_VALUE_TAG, dialog.getProgress());
    }

    public int getProgress(){
        return dialog.getProgress();
    }

    public int getMax(){
        return dialog.getMax();
    }

    public void incrementProgressBy(int value){
        if (dialog.getProgress() + value <= dialog.getMax())
            dialog.incrementProgressBy(value);
    }

}
```

In the `onPostExecute()` method I need to perform some UI update so here's my problem: if I start the dialog and the AsyncTask (like above) and I don't rotate my phone, all works as expected. Same thing if I rotate phone AFTER the `onPostExecute()` method. But if I rotate my phone WHILE the AsyncTask is still running, when it completes and reach the `onPostExecute()` method it gives me the `IllegalStateException` saying that the fragment hosting the AsyncTask and the Dialogfragment is no longer attached to the activity. So I tried to override both the `onAttach()` and the `onDetach()` methods (with a simple `System.out.println`) of my fragment, to see when the `onPostExecute()` gets called. The result is that when I rotate my phone, I always got this output:

```
onDetach
onAttach
... (if I rotate more my phone)
onPostExecute
```

So shouldn't the fragment be attached when the AsyncTask completes? Thank you all for your time and attention.

Comment: I would suggest using just a `ProgressDialog`, because you are in just inflating a dialog in a `DialogFragment`. It seems redundant and there is so much extra code. Also, you need to check if your `fragment` is still attached to your `activity` in `onPostExecute` using `isFinishing`, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing().

Comment: Hi Jared, thank you for your answer. For the ProgressDialog suggestion I think I'll definitely follow it, so thanks. For the `isFinishing` method, I've tried to put a `System.out.println(getActivity().isFinishing())` in the `onPostExecute`: if I don't rotate my phone it writes "false" on the console and, in fact, all works as expected. But if I rotate my phone, my app crash because `getActivity()` returns null.

Comment: Yes, because the activity is recreated. So you need a `if (isFisinishing()) return;`.

Comment: But I need to refresh my UI, I can't simply return. I need to show user the AsyncTask results.

Comment: Actually in your `onCreate` have you tried `setRetainInstance(boolean)`? I use this in all my apps. So use a regular fragment + dialog.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417885/android-fragments-retaining-an-asynctask-during-screen-rotation-or-configuratio

Comment: I tried it, but using `setRetainInstance(true)` introduce some other complications (for example, my DialogFragment stops update it's ProgressDialog after rotations). If possible I'd like to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally managed to solve this problem by stop using `AsyncTask` and using [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) + [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) following this [article](http://android.codeandmagic.org/android-fragments-saving-state-and-screen-rotation/). In short, your fragment must implement the [LoaderCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html) interface and manage the `AsyncTaskLoader`. A skeleton fragment could be something like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate here your view as you usually do and find your components
        // For example imagine to have a button tha will fire the task
        Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Use this to start task for the first time
                getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
                // .. or this for restart the task, details in
                // the provided article
                // getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
            }
        });

        // Get fragments load manager
        LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
        if (lm.getLoader(0) != null) {
            // Reconnect to an existing loader
            lm.initLoader(0, null, this);
        }

        // Return your view here
        return view;
    }

    // LoaderCallbacks methods to override
    @Override
    public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // Create an instance of the loader passing the context
        MyTaskLoader loader = new MyTaskLoader(getActivity());
        loader.forceLoad();
        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Object data) {
        // Use this callback as you would use the AsyncTask "onPostExecute"
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {}

    // Now define the loader class
    private static class MyTaskLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader {
        public MyTaskLoader(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public Object loadInBackground() {
            // Do here your async work
        }
    }

}
```