# Why I'm getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException during android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setTargetFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

After upgrading my app to

- targetSdkVersion 27
- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2

I am getting the following crash log from live

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setTargetFragment (Fragment.java:545)
```

I look at the source code of support fragment (Not exactly line 545. I'm not sure how I can get the latest source code of support fragment library)

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/cef09fe/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java#598

```
598 public void setTargetFragment(Fragment fragment, int requestCode) {
599     mTarget = fragment;
560     mTargetRequestCode = requestCode;
561 }
```

I can't see a reason why `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` is thrown. Maybe I'm looking at wrong version of support library source code?

Do you have any idea, why I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` during `android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setTargetFragment`

---

My source code is as follow

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class BuyPortfolioFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        // If not retained (or first time running), we need to create it.
        if (this.statusBarUpdaterFragment == null) {
            this.statusBarUpdaterFragment = StatusBarUpdaterFragment.newInstance();
            // Tell it who it is working with.
            this.statusBarUpdaterFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(statusBarUpdaterFragment, STATUS_BAR_UPDATER_FRAGMENT).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } else {
            statusBarUpdaterFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        }
```

Comment: Is `fm` `BuyPortfolioFragment`'s child `FragmentManager`? If so, that's likely your problem. You can't set a target with a `Fragment` that belongs to a different `FragmentManager`.

Comment: You're right. `BuyFragment` is a child fragment. I manage to reproduce the problem, and dig in `Fragment` latest source code. It seems Google places new restriction on `setTargetFragment`. Does it mean, I need to use `statusBarUpdaterFragment.setTargetFragment(this.getParentFragment(), 0);` ? Child fragment can no longer communicate directly with `statusBarUpdaterFragment`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. That is, I don't know what `BuyFragment` is, or what it's parent is. If you mean `BuyPortfolioFragment`, and it's in the `Activity`, then it won't have a parent `Fragment`. However, that `StatusBarUpdaterFragment` can get reference to that `BuyPortfolioFragment` with `getParentFragment()`. You don't really have to use the target `Fragment` there.

Comment: Sorry. Typo in previous reply. `BuyPortfolioFragment` is child fragment of `PortfolioFragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code, which may crash sometimes. You may reproduce, by reducing background process limit to 1.

[image]

```
public class BuyPortfolioFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        // If not retained (or first time running), we need to create it.
        if (this.statusBarUpdaterFragment == null) {
            this.statusBarUpdaterFragment = StatusBarUpdaterFragment.newInstance();
            // Tell it who it is working with.
            this.statusBarUpdaterFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(statusBarUpdaterFragment, STATUS_BAR_UPDATER_FRAGMENT).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } else {
            statusBarUpdaterFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        }
```

Note, calling `setTargetFragment` might not be always necessary due to [Is calling setTargetFragment on headless fragment no longer necessary during UI fragment re-creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326206/is-calling-settargetfragment-on-headless-fragment-no-longer-necessary-during-ui)

However, to play a safe game, I use the following fix.

```
public class BuyPortfolioFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...

        // If not retained (or first time running), we need to create it.
        if (this.statusBarUpdaterFragment == null) {
            this.statusBarUpdaterFragment = StatusBarUpdaterFragment.newInstance();
            // Tell it who it is working with.
            this.statusBarUpdaterFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            fm.beginTransaction().add(statusBarUpdaterFragment, STATUS_BAR_UPDATER_FRAGMENT).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } else {
            // Google poses new restriction recently. A fragment need to have same fragment
            // manager as StatusBarUpdaterFragment, in order to become its target fragment. It
            // is OK not to call setTargetFragment. Although you may get null from
            // statusBarUpdaterFragment.getTargetFragment, during onResume,
            // statusBarUpdaterFragment.getTargetFragment will magically return correct fragment.

            //statusBarUpdaterFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        ...

        // This code block might not be necessary. Just to be safe.
        if (statusBarUpdaterFragment != null) {
            // Google poses new restriction recently. A fragment need to have same fragment
            // manager as StatusBarUpdaterFragment, in order to become its target fragment. It
            // is OK not to call setTargetFragment. Although you may get null from
            // statusBarUpdaterFragment.getTargetFragment, during onResume,
            // statusBarUpdaterFragment.getTargetFragment will magically return correct fragment.

            try {
                statusBarUpdaterFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
            } catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // Shouldn't happen. Just to be safe.
                Log.e(TAG, "", e);
            }
        }
```