# Android: service binding lost when orientation changes

Tags: android, service, bind, screen-orientation

I have a music player activity with a service which plays the music. When the screen orientation changes I loose the binding with the service and therefore I can't stop it. I can see this because "Play" button which previoulsy had stop icon has again play icon - so the interface kinda resets.

How to solve this?

Comment: were you able to get this done for a service not for a async task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this question: [How to handle an AsyncTask during Screen Rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620917/how-to-handle-an-asynctask-during-screen-rotation)

try the accepted answer that is there. (If it works for you vote it up there, not me.)

If your specific application requires that you need to do some work when the rotation happens then you'll have to also override the `onConfigurationChanged()` inside your activity and put whatever work you need to do there.