# Android screen rotation causes exception

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a lot ot async tasks in my activity. If screen rotation occurs - they gone. What to do to prevent asynctasks from trowing exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle an AsyncTask during Screen Rotation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620917/how-to-handle-an-asynctask-during-screen-rotation)

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Comment: Null pointer. Is avtivity still alive?...

Comment: Here is how you disable landspace http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2014/06/activity-screen-rotationorientation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think exception  is due to the re starting of the activity in orientation changes, if use `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` for your activity in your manifest, which prevents restart

Comment: I'm planning to use different layout for portrait and landscape. this will cause other problems.

Comment: im not sure why people recommend this as a fix. this is just a cheap way to ignore the fact that you should be properly handling orientation changes

Answer (score 1):

use

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

as a attribute of your `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file  to prevent reload Activity on screen rotation .

Answer (score 0):

The most proper way to this is to use a fragment to retain the instance of the async task, over rotations.

Here is a link to very simple example making it easy to follow and integrate this technique into your apps. This works brilliantly all buttons and images etc are redrawn as expected

https://gist.github.com/daichan4649/2480065