# android multithreading and network on main thread exception;

Tags: android

Consider the scenario where I have get data from server and post it to UI in say list view , but this is an going activity ,it never stops.

```
taskA{ //fetches data over network

if(!update)
    fetch();//network operation

}

taskB{//using this data UI is updated at runtime just like feed.

if(update)
    show();//UI operation
}
```

taskA starts first after it completes taskB starts by that time A is sleeping and vice versa , goes , now the problems i am facing are:

1. both operations have to be in worker thread
2. both operations are going in cycle till activity is alive.
3. if handler is used to post UI operation to the main thread , taskB seems to stop.

Can anybody please suggest me a design to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsyncTask` is doing the job for you. You can make it as an inner class under your `Activity` main class.

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Example code

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {
     protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         // Fetch Data (Task A)
         return "Result";
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         // Show progress
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         // Show UI after complete (Task B)
     }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but it's only correct if the activity does not rotate when user rotates device.

Comment: The handling is not that complicated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620917/how-to-handle-an-asynctask-during-screen-rotation for more concrete solutions.

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong , but if i use asynctask for recurring operation like taskA , then it will create a new thread everytime to do the same operation.

Comment: I am not sure what your operation looks like, but if you are worried about this issue, you may want to use singleton instance for fetching data. Logically, you won't fetch from the same data source multiple times at the same time.

Comment: The operation is similar to producer consumer problem , except that it is an ongoing operation.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` is what you're looking for. Check out this link for some sample code:
http://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/asynctask-call-web-services-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) you can check some [sample code](https://github.com/search?q=android.app.IntentService%20repo%3aandroid/platform_development%20repo%3acommonsguy/cw-omnibus%20extension%3ajava&type=Code)

An Android service is lightweight but more complex to setup.

AsyncTask is very easy but not recommended as it has many downsides and flaws.
You could also look into [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) but it's not as easy as AsyncTasks.