# How to handle a running AsyncTask during orientation/configuration change?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-orientation

I know this question has been discussed several times like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620917/how-to-handle-an-asynctask-during-screen-rotation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128670/best-practice-asynctask-during-orientation-change).

But my problem is still not solved because most solutions provided are either not suggested or deprecated.

I have an `AsyncTask` in which I update a `TextView` text continuously. The execution of the task is started in a toggle button click. Initially I had the `AsyncTask` as an inner class to the main activity. But I later changed it to an external class.

I am using `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` methods to store and restore the textview value during an orientation change. What I am not able to achieve is after the orientation, how do I restore the button state and also resume the `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this page : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config, if your application targets API level 13 or higher, you should use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to catch the screen rotation into the `onConfigurationChanged()` method.

By doing this, the `onPause` and `onResume` methods are not called, so your TextView will keep its value. And in my mind, it won't stop the running AsyncTask. If it does, try to recall it in the `onConfigurationChanged` method.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `Application` class, it's always available, and store the task in a static variable there.
2. Add a dummy fragment to activity with `setRetainInstance(true)`, use it to store and run AsyncTasks. It will auto-attach on rotation and Activity can find it again by tag.
3. Use a Service to run background stuff, background services are unaffected by rotation restarts, Activity can bind to it again.

Comment: Its a bad idea to introduce static instances where `Context` is involved. It is prone to memory leaks.

Comment: @Waqas Nope. Application class is effectively a singleton already, it is destroyed last.

Comment: what if your activity context is referenced in that AsyncTask which is static?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just save the button state into the bundle in `onSaveInstanceState(...)`, and restore it during `onCreate(...)`, and hence resume the AsyncTask depending on the button state?  Note, my experience is that it's onCreate(..) that normally gets called after an orientation change, rather than `onRestoreInstanceState()`.