# Listview Destroyed on Oreintation change

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

So, I have a simple app which tracks the calories and fat I take in in a day and totals them for me. works fantastically in portrait orientation, but when I go into landscape, the listview is destroyed, and it seems that the array adapter is also empty. I have boon all over StackOverflow and tried several answers, but none are working. I was under the impression that when the orientation changed, the activity got re-created in onCreate() and that the listView would re-populate from there

## Some of the solutions I have tried

### 1. Handle orentatin changes myself

by overriding onConfigurationChanged() as per this SO answer 
[How to handle an AsyncTask during Screen Rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620917/how-to-handle-an-asynctask-during-screen-rotation)

### 2. Override onResume() to recreate the listview

what I don't understand about this solution is that to my understanding onResume is called after onCreate anyway, so the listview wold have been recreated already

### 3. Referenced this opensource code for a simalar app (uses the above onResume method)

https://github.com/Asdamp/Xday/blob/master/src/com/asdamp/x_day/MainActivity.java

I figure there is something wrong in oncreate, so here is that code

```
  private  ListView foodItemsList;
private DatabaseHelper db;
private ArrayList<FoodItem> allFoods;
private  FoodArrayAdapter foodsAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_foods);
    foodItemsList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.food_items_list);
    allFoods= (ArrayList<FoodItem>) db.getTodaysFoods();
    foodsAdapter = new FoodArrayAdapter( this, allFoods);



    // set the footer for the list
    View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.food_list_footer, null, false);
    foodItemsList.addFooterView(footerView);
    foodItemsList.setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

    //set the listview to use this adapter
    foodItemsList.setAdapter(foodsAdapter);

       updateTotalDailyCalories();
        updateTotalDailyFat();


}
```

at a loss here, any help here would save my but 
The real mistory is that the array list is null after orientation change.........

## EDIT: my onResume was wrong

This code fixed the issue

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // check if the listview is null
    if (foodItemsList==null){
        // get a refference to it and re create it

        foodItemsList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.food_items_list);
        // get the data again
        allFoods=(ArrayList<FoodItem>)db.getTodaysFoods();
        foodsAdapter.setListData(allFoods);
        foodsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

I Still Dont understand why onResume needs to do that, when onCreate already populates the listview, and is called on orientation changes anyway. Can someone enlighten me?